# Centering a multi-column cell on top of two cells

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multicolumn

I am new to Latex and it is just so hard to build a table there. I am using overleaf as a provider.
I am having a problem in adjusting the cells of muilt-column cells to be centered. I have looked online and there are so many answers. However, in my case, they all did not work for some reason. Could someone help me?

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Performance Metrics for Weather-Insensitive and Weather-Aware Models.\label{Table2}}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-\extralength}{0cm}
        \newcolumntype{c}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
        \begin{tabularx}{\fulllength}{cccccccc}
            \toprule 
            && \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{RMSE}}    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{AAE}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{MAPE}} & \\
            \textbf{Location}   & \textbf{Prediction Interval}  & Weather-insensitive & Weather-aware & Weather-insensitive & Weather-aware &Weather-insensitive & Weather-aware \\
            \hline
            & t+5 & 4.98 & 4.99& 2.94& 2.94&4.11&4.22 \\
            \multirow{1}{*}{A} & t+10 &6.7&5.85&3.49&3.33&5.51&4.71 \\
            & t+15 &7.84&7.97&4.07&4.10&6.74&6.83\\
            \hline
            & t+5 &4.23&    4.21&   2.56    &2.57   &3.47   &3.47\\
            \multirow{1}{*}{B} & t+10   &5.80&  5.53&   3.24&   3.14&   4.50
            & 4.33 \\
            & t+15& 6.27&   6.12&   3.45&   3.40&   4.96&   4.90\\
            \hline
            & t+5&  5.32&   5.27&   2.97&   3.00&   4.38&   4.32\\
            \multirow{1}{*}{C} & t+10   &6.03   &6.07&  3.26&   3.24&   5.10&   5.07 \\
            & t+15&     6.66&   6.64&   3.51&   3.49&   5.53&   5.52\\
            \hline
             &  t+5 &5.00   &4.90&  2.65&   2.61&   3.28&   3.21\\
            \multirow{1}{*}{D} &t+10&   6.75&   6.52&   3.25&   3.19&   4.15&   4.10 \\
            & t+15  & 7.20  & 7.18&     3.65&   3.60&   4.77&   4.64\\

            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}
```

The output is [image]
RMSE, AAE, and MAPE should be centered over each two columns.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please extend your cofe fragment to complete small document. Table code contain commands which probably are defined in document preamble. Also please test your table. It contains errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the instruction

```
\newcolumntype{c}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

is extraordinarily dangerous, as the `c` column type is defined in and gets used in lots of places throughout the LaTeX kernel. I suggest you use `C`, not `c`, as the name of the new column type.

Next, the `\multirow` instructions don't seem to do anything useful. (To have a chance at being useful, the first argument of `\multirow` should be greater than 1.) I'd therefore omit the `\multirow` wrappers.

Finally, the table's header is very crowded. I suggest you simplify it massively, maybe along the lines employed in the following example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \smash[b] macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash[b]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} C @{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default value: 6pt
\caption{Performance metrics for weather-insensitive (W-I) and weather-aware (W-A) models.\strut} \label{Table2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{8}{C} @{}}
\toprule 
\mytab{Location} & \mytab{Prediction Interval} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{RMSE} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{AAE} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{MAPE} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(l){7-8}
 & & W-I & W-A & W-I & W-A & W-I & W-A \\[1.5ex]
\midrule
  & $t+\phantom{0}5$ & 4.98 & 4.99 & 2.94 & 2.94 & 4.11 & 4.22 \\
A & $t+10$ & 6.70 & 5.85 & 3.49 & 3.33 & 5.51 & 4.71 \\
  & $t+15$ & 7.84 & 7.97 & 4.07 & 4.10 & 6.74 & 6.83 \\
\addlinespace
  & $t+\phantom{0}5$ & 4.23 & 4.21 & 2.56 & 2.57 & 3.47 & 3.47 \\
B & $t+10$ & 5.80 & 5.53 & 3.24 & 3.14 & 4.50 & 4.33 \\
  & $t+15$ & 6.27 & 6.12 & 3.45 & 3.40 & 4.96 & 4.90 \\
\addlinespace
  & $t+\phantom{0}5$ & 5.32 & 5.27 & 2.97 & 3.00 & 4.38 & 4.32 \\
C & $t+10$ & 6.03 & 6.07 & 3.26 & 3.24 & 5.10 & 5.07 \\
  & $t+15$ & 6.66 & 6.64 & 3.51 & 3.49 & 5.53 & 5.52 \\
\addlinespace
  & $t+\phantom{0}5$ & 5.00 & 4.90 & 2.65 & 2.61 & 3.28 & 3.21 \\
D & $t+10$ & 6.75 & 6.52 & 3.25 & 3.19 & 4.15 & 4.10 \\
  & $t+15$ & 7.20 & 7.18 & 3.65 & 3.60 & 4.77 & 4.64 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. However, how can I change the width to page width?

Comment: @MustafaKamal -- Umm, by "page width", to you mean the parameter `\paperwidth`, which equals `\textwidth` plus both side margins? If that's what you want, just change `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}` to `\begin{tabularx}{\paperwidth}`. Don't be surprised by the fact that the tabular material will spill over massively into the right-hand margin.

Comment: Mico, Thanks.  I wanted to make the table as wide as the page. However, I could figure that our!

Answer (score 3):

I try to follow your table design. After removing all errors (among them dangerous redefined default column type `c`) in your code fragment and guessing how your document preamble can be, I construct the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{0cm}{-\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}
\caption{Performance Metrics for Weather-Insensitive and Weather-Aware Models.\label{Table2}}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} c c *{6}{C} @{}}
    \toprule
    &       &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{RMSE}}    
                            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{AAE}}
                                            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{MAPE}}      
                                                                    \\
    \cmidrule(rl){3-4}  \cmidrule(rl){5-6}  \cmidrule(rl){7-8}
\textbf{Location}   
    & \thead[t]{Prediction\\ Interval}  
            & Weather-insensitive 
                    & Weather-aware 
                            & Weather-insensitive 
                                    & Weather-aware 
                                            & Weather-insensitive 
                                                    & Weather-aware \\
    \midrule
    & t+5   & 4.98  & 4.99  & 2.94  & 2.94  & 4.11  & 4.22  \\
A   & t+10  & 6.7   & 5.85  & 3.49  & 3.33  & 5.51  & 4.71  \\
    & t+15  & 7.84  & 7.97  & 4.07  & 4.10  & 6.74  & 6.83  \\
    \midrule
    & t+5   & 4.23  & 4.21  & 2.56  & 2.57  & 3.47  & 3.47  \\
B   & t+10  & 5.80  & 5.53  & 3.24  & 3.14  & 4.50  & 4.33  \\
    & t+15  & 6.27  &¸6.12  & 3.45  & 3.40  & 4.96  & 4.90  \\
    \midrule
    & t+5   &  5.32 & 5.27  & 2.97  & 3.00  & 4.38  & 4.32  \\
C   & t+10  & 6.03  & 6.07  & 3.26  & 3.24  & 5.10  & 5.07  \\
    & t+15  & 6.66  & 6.64  & 3.51  & 3.49  & 5.53  & 5.52  \\
    \midrule
    &  t+5  & 5.00  & 4.90  & 2.65  & 2.61  & 3.28  & 3.21  \\
D   & t+10  & 6.75  & 6.52  & 3.25  & 3.19  & 4.15  & 4.10  \\
    & t+15  & 7.20  & 7.18  & 3.65  & 3.60  & 4.77  & 4.64  \\
    \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your table, there's so much white space caused by long phrases. The simplest approach is to use something shorter, acronyms, and move their explanation somewhere else (to the title or a list of annotations). Probably the table itself would need another think-thought.

Secondly, `\label` should be placed after `\caption{}`, not inside.

Another thing is you have redefined `c` column type. You should never do that. It gives unpredictable behaviour and makes really hard to debug it.

The reason all column of groups of 2 are not aligned as expected is because you have added an extra column separator `&`.

After a few quick changes, the table can fit the standard page and has more room for improvement.

EDIT. The title looks awful but I deliberately left it as is because it may still need re-wording. If you wish to reduce its width, you could wrap it inside a `minipage`, e.g.

```
\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
  \caption{Performance Metrics for Weather-Insensitive and Weather-Aware Models.}
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % For \Centering and \RaggedRight
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=3pt, position=top, format=hang}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
  \centering
  \caption{Performance Metrics for Weather-Insensitive and Weather-Aware Models.}
  \label{Table2}
  \newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}
  \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft}p{#1}}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{P{1.25cm} p{1cm} *6{C}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Location}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{PI}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{RMSE}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{AAE}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{MAPE}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-8}
    &
    & W-i   % Weather-intensive
    & W-a   % Weather-aware
    & W-i
    & W-a
    & W-i
    & W-a \\
    \midrule
    & t+5  & 4.98 & 4.99 & 2.94 & 2.94 & 4.11 & 4.22 \\
    A & t+10 & 6.7  & 5.85 & 3.49 & 3.33 & 5.51 & 4.71 \\
    & t+15 & 7.84 & 7.97 & 4.07 & 4.10 & 6.74 & 6.83 \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & t+5  & 4.23 & 4.21 & 2.56 & 2.57 & 3.47 & 3.47 \\
    B & t+10 & 5.80 & 5.53 & 3.24 & 3.14 & 4.50 & 4.33 \\
    & t+15 & 6.27 & 6.12 & 3.45 & 3.40 & 4.96 & 4.90 \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & t+5  & 5.32 & 5.27 & 2.97 & 3.00 & 4.38 & 4.32 \\
    C & t+10 & 6.03 & 6.07 & 3.26 & 3.24 & 5.10 & 5.07 \\
    & t+15 & 6.66 & 6.64 & 3.51 & 3.49 & 5.53 & 5.52 \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & t+5  & 5.00 & 4.90 & 2.65 & 2.61 & 3.28 & 3.21 \\
    D & t+10 & 6.75 & 6.52 & 3.25 & 3.19 & 4.15 & 4.10 \\
    & t+15 & 7.20 & 7.18 & 3.65 & 3.60 & 4.77 & 4.64 \\
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{\rule{0pt}{2.75ex}\textbf{PI}: Prediction Interval,\qquad W-i: Wather-intensive,\qquad W-a: Weather-aware}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```